# error loading images and JS files in a web app

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, web-applications

After creating some sub folders under WEB-INF like js or images,i found problems loading their files i can not obtain any js or image files...what it could be the problem?.
I got this error on the browser :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/images/blueAqua.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You are mising your context here 


    `http://localhost:8080/contextName/images/blueAqua.gif`

Answer (score 1):

`WEB-INF` is not accessible client-side.

I usually create a `static` folder next to the `WEB-INF` one, to store images, JS, CSS, etc.

```
webapp
|__static
|  |__css
|  |__js
|  |__img
|__WEB-INF
   |__web.xml
```

Then, access the resources using:

```
http://localhost:8080/static/images/blueAqua.gif
```

Comment: The point `WEB-INF is not accessible client-side.` OP not accessing that directly. Making a request for the resource. Context is missing. That's the problem.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Context can be missing as well, but anyway, if OP put static resources within the WEB-INF folder, the browser won't be able to access them. Have a try if you doubt.

Comment: i tried to add the static folder but nothing changed..:( here is a screen shot on my project hierarchy i left the old files just in case   http://clip2net.com/s/iGIU4k

Comment: @Neeldz What server are you using? Jetty, Tomcat? Do you have a context path set?

Comment: @sp00m am using Tomcat

Comment: @Neeldz Could you provide your <tomcat_home>/conf/server.xml file?

Comment: @Neeldz PS: have a look at my edit: you have to use `http://localhost:8080/static/images/blueAqua.gif` URL, is it the one you tried?

Comment: still not working ...is there is any modification should be done in web.xml ? its just am calling this image with the usual html tag from the jsp file under WEB-INF !!

Comment: @Neeldz What exact URL do you use to access the welcome page of your webapp?

Comment: @sp00m am using this link `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTutorial/sample` for the first page i dont know if that change anything but am using Spring in this web and yes i did try ur latest link it still not working

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTutorial/static/images/blueAqua.gif`. `/SpringMVCTutorial` seems to be your context path.

Comment: @sp00m no man not working ... just wondering what it will be the right path in the jsp file to catch the image i tried to use the full src path but no success

Answer (score 0):

It work fines now i did realise what was the problem and how to fix it, it needed just some configuration in the web.xml as below:

`<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
and in the JSP file it was the call like this :

`<body background="static/images/example.jpg">`
thx for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```